# Retrofit 2 onResponse method not called although Http request returns data

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am making an asynchronous http request, calling a web service which returns a list of game dates in JSON format. I can see in my log that data is being returned, however neither the `onResponse` nor `onFailure` methods are being called.

Following are my code fragments followed by the log showing the results of the http request. Note that the web service being called is only being asked to return 1 column out of 30 (`gameDate`) from the `Games` table. There are two rows in the table and the `gameDate` column is being returned from both rows as seen in the log. I am attempting to pass the game date list back to my main activity for display.

Does anyone have an idea why neither the `onResponse` nor the `onFailure` methods are being reached?

```
public interface GamesAPI {

    @GET("/HCDBWebService/HCDBWebService.php?format=json&operation=gameList")
    Call<List<Game>> listGames();

}




private void requestData() {

    Log.d("MainActivity.LOGTAG", "requestData method");

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    GamesAPI api = retrofit.create(GamesAPI.class);

    Call<List<Game>> call = api.listGames();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Game>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Game>> call, Response<List<Game>> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                gameList = response.body();
            } else {
                Log.e("Error code", String.valueOf(response.code()));
                Log.e("Error body", response.errorBody().toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Game>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

LOG OUTPUT:

```
 D/OkHttp: Date: Thu, 22 Sep 2016 13:42:54 GMT
 D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.12 PHP/7.0.10 mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.2h DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0
 D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.10
 D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 53
 D/OkHttp: Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
 D/OkHttp: Connection: Keep-Alive
 D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json
 D/OkHttp: [{"gameDate":"2016-09-15"},{"gameDate":"2016-09-19"}]
 D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (53-byte body)
```

Comment: Please add at least a question

Comment: My question was embedded in my text.  I just edited and appended to the end of my text (  Does anyone have an idea why neither the onResponse nor the onFailure methods are being reached?)

Comment: Nothing stands out as incorrect. This may sound dumb, but have you tried logging something if `response.isSuccessful()`? You are setting `gameList = response.body()`, but maybe you never actually use the `gameList` *after* the value gets set?

Comment: That are good questions, Bryan.  I hadn't tried logging if response.isSuccessful() so I just inserted a log and reran.  The same thing is happening.  As I step thru in debug mode the cursor goes from the call.enqueue line directly to the closing brace of the call.enqueue method.  To answer you other question, gameList is actually referenced following the call to my getRequest() method.  I'll show you that code here: 
                requestData();
                GameAdapter gameAdapter = new GameAdapter(this, R.layout.game_list_item, gameList);
                list.setAdapter(gameAdapter);

Comment: try to update de Game adapter list, gameList.addAll(response.body())
try to log in the onResponse method to ensure you we're there

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I have tried the logging already as per @Bryan and your idea to use the gameList.add object  but am still not hitting the onResponse method when I step through the logic.  Again OkHttp is showing that json data is being retrieved but the logic to process it isn't being reached.  I may try version 1.9 to see if I have a better result.

Comment: Version 1.9 of what? What version are you on now?

Comment: I am new to Retrofit and started with version 2.1.  I'm talking about trying Retrofit 1.9 if I can't get it to work with 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too late, but I try to answer your question. Your problem with List<..>. Just change all `**List<Game>**` to `**Game**` where you use them. It should help.

**Example:**

From

```
Call<List<Game>> call = api.listGames();
```

To

```
Call<Game> call = api.listGames();
```